# Pasar variable a clase cursorAdapter desde activity

Tags: java, android, adapter

Tengo  datos cargandose en un listview con cursorAdapter personalizado, mi duda está en como puedo pasar una variable al cursor adapter desde el activity donde llamar al cursor, no se si me entiendan.

Intente pasarle por el constructor

```
mProdcutoAdapter=new SelectCursorAdapterProductos(this,null,codcabecera);
```

asi en la clase adapter

```
  public SelectCursorAdapterProductos(Context context, Cursor c, String cod) {
    super(context, c, 0);
    codpedido=cod;
}
```

pero no le asigna el codigo a la variable que necesito, la variable codpedido sigue en null

Comment: agrega tu código.

Comment: Es corrrecto lo que realizas, simplemente que codcabecera tiene valor null!, verifica que al instanciar el Adapter el valor de codcabecera sea correcto. @Alldesignweb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Pasar variable a clase cursorAdapter desde activity

Esto debe ser al instanciar tu Adapter, puedes modificar el constructor para que reciba la variable y sea usada en el Adapter, por ejemplo:

```
private String valor;

 public SelectCursorAdapterProductos(Context context, Cursor c, String cod, String valor) {
    super(context, c, 0);
    codpedido=cod;
    //valor recibido a travez del constructor.
    this.valor = valor;
}
```

por lo tanto al instanciar tu Adapter en tu Activity envias el valor:

```
mProdcutoAdapter = new SelectCursorAdapterProductos(this,null,codcabecera, "Alldesign Web");
```

---

**Es corrrecto lo que realizas, simplemente que `codcabecera` tiene valor null!, verifica que al instanciar el Adapter el valor de `codcabecera` sea correcto.**

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente esta no sea la respuesta correcta pero ami me ha funcionado muy bien al pasar una variable de la Activity al Adapter

```
Activity---
    public static String mInfoFoto;
       ejemplo 1.- (mInfoFoto = getIntent().getExtras().getString(EXTRA_BOLEAN_PICTURE);)
       ejemplo 2 = mInfoFoto = "HolaMundo"

   public static String getMyVariablePicture() {
        return mInfoFoto;
    }
------
Adapter

    private String getVariableBolean = MainMultimediaActivity.getMyVariablePicture();
```